# AddAzureSignalR and ServerStickyMode with two Azure SignalR resources

Tags: azure, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

Currently we have a configuration of two Azure SignalR services and two web app services that are configured with the two signalr services (below code). My question is whether ServerStickyMode is required since the documentation is confusing, we have documentation that says its mostly not required since we are using a Azure SignalR service and a post that says it is required, I ran into issues with it disabled it does not work all the time, just intermittently, so it really is required. Would the amount of instances (sku units) also affect ServerStickyMode?

*Not Required?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/scale?view=aspnetcore-7.0#azure-signalr-service

"*The only circumstances in which sticky sessions are not required are:"
When using the Azure SignalR Service.
"Sticky sessions, also known as client affinity, is not required, because clients are immediately redirected to the Azure SignalR Service when they connect.*"

*Required?

[https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/whats-new-in-azure-signalr-1-1-0-preview-1/#:~:text=Also%20when%20sticky%20mode%20is%20enabled%2C%20service%20won%E2%80%99t,only%20enable%20it%20when%20there%20is%20a%20need](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/whats-new-in-azure-signalr-1-1-0-preview-1/#:%7E:text=Also%20when%20sticky%20mode%20is%20enabled%2C%20service%20won%E2%80%99t,only%20enable%20it%20when%20there%20is%20a%20need).

"*The typical connection flow when using SignalR service is that client first negotiates with app server to get the url of SignalR service, then service routes client to app server.
When you have multiple app servers, there is no guarantee that two servers (the one who does negotiation and the one who gets the hub invocation) will be the same one.
We hear a lot of customers asking about whether it’s possible to make the two servers the same one so they can share some states between negotiation and hub invocation. In this release we have added a new “server sticky mode” to support this scenario.
To enable this, you just need to set ServerStickyMode to Required in AddAzureSignalR():*"

Any help would be appreciated.

```
 .AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR(options =>
                {
                    options.Endpoints = new[]
                    {
                        new ServiceEndpoint(configuration["SignalRConnectionStringPrimary"],
                            EndpointType.Primary, "Primary"),
                        new ServiceEndpoint(configuration["SignalRConnectionStringSecondary"],
                            EndpointType.Primary, "Secondary")
                        options.ServerStickyMode = ServerStickyMode.Disabled;
                    };
```

I am expecting that any published data on SignalR will be received by the subscribers.